# Having Issue on Pushing Strings Between Parantsis Into Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to create an Array of Arrays like this

```
[
  ["-0.75_-1.25_-1.75_-2.25"],
  ["-0.75_-1.25_-1.75_-2.25"]
]
```

from an string like:

```
"-9.00_-6.50,-6.00_+6.00(-0.75_-1.25_-1.75_-2.25)(-0.75_-1.25_-1.75_-2.25)"
```

by pushing a all strings which are between `( )`. I tried this using this `.match(/[^()]+/g)` regex but this adding all of content to the array and it is only one array like

```
[
  [
    "-9.00_-6.50,-6.00_+6.00",
    "-0.75_-1.25_-1.75_-2.25",
    "-0.75_-1.25_-1.75_-2.25"
  ]
]
```

can you please let me know how to fix this?

```js
var data = "-9.00_-6.50,-6.00_+6.00(-0.75_-1.25_-1.75_-2.25)(-0.75_-1.25_-1.75_-2.25)"; 
var dataarr = [];
dataarr.push(data.match(/[^()]+/g));
console.log(dataarr);
```

Comment: Matches of `(?<=\()[^)]+(?=\))` comprise the array `["-0.75_-1.25_-1.75_-2.25", "-0.75_-1.25_-1.75_-2.25"]`. Converting each of its elements `e` to `[e]` is simple, though I don't know why you'd want to do so.

Comment: check my answer! u can solve using regex.

Comment: @xdeepakv, the OP is informed by SO when answers are submitted, so your comment is superfluous. Moreover, all the answers employ a regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could slice the matched result, map the strings with wrapping and get arrays in an array.

```js
var data = "-9.00_-6.50,-6.00_+6.00(-0.75_-1.25_-1.75_-2.25)(-0.75_-1.25_-1.75_-2.25)",
    result = data
        .match(/[^()]+/g)
        .slice(1)
        .map(s => [s]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not need `split`, `map` loop. You can do using regex only. Just create a `match all` function.

```
function matchAll(re, str) {
  let result = [];
  let m = null;
  do {
    m = re.exec(str);
    if (m) {
      result.push(m[1]);
    }
  } while (m);
  return result;
}
```

```js
function matchAll(re, str) {
  let result = [];
  let m = null;
  do {
    m = re.exec(str);
    if (m) {
      result.push(m[1]);
    }
  } while (m);
  return result;
}

const s =
  "-9.00_-6.50,-6.00_+6.00(-0.75_-1.25_-1.75_-2.25)(-0.75_-1.25_-1.75_-2.25)";
const re = /\((.+?)\)/g;
console.log(matchAll(re, s));
```